# How do I save a foreign key only by its ID?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a simplish type:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public virtual TestList MyList { get; set; }
public int MyListID { get; set; }
```

---

TestList simply has ID and Name - nothing else.

I then have a create view that enumerates the testlist to a dropdown which I see the correct ID successfully passed back to the controller.

My problem is that, when I try to map the ViewModel to the backend model by:

```
prop.MyListID = model.MyListID;
```

I then get an error with foreignkeys as `MyList` in prop is `null`.

I am certain I can fix by doing a `prop.MyList = db.TestList.find(model.MyListID);`, but, this seems a waste of a database query.

I can see from a diagram view that the foreign keys are correct and the MyListID is being used as the FK, but, I just can't figure out how to use only the ID.

Can anyone advise?

Appologies for the mistake in the first type up of this question - made a silly mistake.

Comment: The fact that `MyList` is `virtual ICollection<TestList>` means you have a one-mant relationship so you cannot have a `MyListID` property (it would need to be `IEnumerable<int> MyListIDs` and you would need a `ListBoxFor()`, not a `DropDownListFor()` to select the items. And you would need a table to store the relationships (containing properties for the parent ID and the ListID)

Comment: What is `MyListID` supposed to refer to? It's `TestList` that should have a FK. But you better show the code that throws the exception and also the full exception message.

Comment: Thanks - I screwed up completely - it is only meant to lead to one now. Thanks for pointing this out. Headbang moment.

Comment: I'm a little confused, but, after dropping the DB, it appears to be working, so, fingers crossed it stays this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created one to many relationship (because you use `virtual ICollection<TestList>`), and now EF create new one table to map this relationship, and also you get many IDs in your MyList property, you can add attribute `[ForeignKey("MyListID")]` to your List property, or Map it using Fluent Api :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //one-to-many 
    modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
                .HasRequired<TestList>(s => s.TestList) // This is navigational property (virtual) 
                .WithMany(s => s.MyList); //this is your list
}
```

Then you can get the list `entity.MyList`.

Read more about One to many relationship there - http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Hi, Thanks... many code changes, I missed this completely, I screwed up using ICollection - it doesn't need a one to many, I'll drop the ICollection.

Comment: I'm still getting the error - I will change the code in the question without the ICollection

Comment: Dropped the DB, recreated and it appears to be working... Fingers crossed and thanks for your help